# Custom image size mixes width and height in output

Tags: thumbnails, images

I want to use a couple of custom image sizes for a site that I'm developing. When I output the images I sometimes do not get the correct width size because it is mixed up with the height size. It guess it has something to do with how I declare the image sizes in the functions file.

functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'small', 145, 999 );
add_image_size( 'medium', 300, 999 );
add_image_size( 'large', 455, 999 );
add_image_size( 'tablet', 1024, 9999 );
```

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('custom-field'), 'medium');
print_r($image);
```

gives me

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/example-300x399.jpg
    [1] => 225
    [2] => 300
    [3] => 1
)
```

Notice the width size is no. 2 in the array, when it usually is 1. Is the output order different if the image is taller then wider? The "errors" that I get are all from vertical images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "medium" and "large" are not custom image sizes - they are already part of the core WordPress media sizes and they should be handled via the "settings" -> "media" options page in wp-admin.

Give your custom image sizes a different and more unique name (reserved are thumbnail, medium, large, full)